# I would like to make my icon clickable to make a phone call

Tags: php, mobile, font-awesome

Good day!

I would like to make my .fa .fa-phone clickable to make a call, but I am not sure. This is the first time I am using php. I would appreciate the help. Here is the code I am using for it.

```
<?php if (!empty($agent_mobile_number)): ?>
      <a title="Mobile Number" href="<?php echo esc_url($agent_mobile_number); ?>?call">
         <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
      </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Try: `<a title="Mobile Number" href="tel:<?php echo esc_url($agent_mobile_number); ?>">` ?

Answer (score 0):

please try

when we want to dial via the international trunk (Assuming your mobile number is saved along with countrycode...)

```
<?php if (!empty($agent_mobile_number)): ?>
      <a title="Mobile Number" href="tel:+<?php echo esc_url($agent_mobile_number); ?>">
        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
      </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

if you want to dial withing your country

```
  <?php if (!empty($agent_mobile_number)): ?>
      <a title="Mobile Number" href="tel:00<?php echo esc_url($agent_mobile_number); ?>">
        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
     </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much there, you just need to add the tel: to the href with the telephone number i.e.

```
<a href="tel:<?= esc_url($agent_mobile_number) ?>">Call Me!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to make icon clickable the code is mentioned below:

```html
<a href="tel:+1 (561) 307-6595"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt" style="color: #710426;"></i></a>
<a href="mailto:GoFaithfit@gmail.com"><i class="fas fa-envelope" style="color: #710426;"></i></a>
```

If you wish to use icon and clickable text here is the code.

```html
<i class="fas fa-phone-alt" style="color: #710426;"></i> <a href="tel:+1 (561) 307-6595">+1 (561) 307-6595</a>
<i class="fas fa-envelope" style="color: #710426;"></i> <a href="mailto:GoFaithfit@gmail.com">GoFaithfit@gmail.com</a>
```